# sudo moo commands in mac

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I have gone through following [link](https://superuser.com/questions/119397/sudo-apt-get-moo-and-other-easter-eggs-in-linux). It's pretty interesting. It gives listing of some funny commands over ubuntu & Linux. I am eager to know about commands like these on mac.

Does any one know commands like on mac ?

Comment: it seems to be a one-man question: why don't you append/join your answers together?

Comment: @dag, @sagar: in "list"-style questions, it is traditional to put separate answers in separate posts.

Comment: oops, sorry! I didn't know that: thank you for the information. :D

Comment: Very funny guys here @quack quixote♦ & @dag729.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Lord of the rings.

Type following command on terminal.

cat /usr/share/calendar/calendar.lotr

- Psychotherapist
- launch terminal
- Type emacs to launch emacs
- after launching emacs in terminal press enter only once
- now press Esc + x ( together & watch that - your cursor has gone to the bottom of terminal )
- if your cursor is bottom at terminal - type doctor
- press enter.
- tetris in emacs
- Open the finder
- Open Applications
- Open Utilities
- Open Terminal
- type "emacs"; click enter
- Press ESC + X at the same time
- Type "tetris"
- Play Tetris ! Use the arrow keys to move and rotate the blocks, and press the space to make the blocks fall.

**Press Command + Ctrl + Option + 8 for inverse.**

For further details watch out following links.

See I got some links.

http://www.eeggs.com/tree/1141.html

http://www.eeggs.com/items/43501.html

http://www.eeggs.com/items/46475.html